# Monowall can't connect via Cisco DPC3941B Modem/Router

Tags: router, isp, modem

We have a monowall router behind DPC3941B, having trouble connecting to internet. Just purchased static IP and still can't get it to work. Comcast says everything looks good on their side. Modem is in Bridge Pass-through mode.
On the monowall on WAN interface we tried entering static IP and gateway they gave us and still no go. Also, there is field for entering MAC address, I assume MAC address from the modem, we tried both of them as well.

If we connect desktop directly to the modem we get 169.x.x.x address not our static IP.

What else can we do to get it going?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you Netmask, it should probably be /30 (and I think monowall defaults* to /31).  Comcast should have given you three numbers (well, not counting the two DNS servers):

- Your usable IP address
- The gateway IP
- The Netmask to use

For single static IP accounts, this is usually 255.255.255.252 (or /30).  For reference, see http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php

Also, be sure to set the WAN Type drop-down to 'Static' in the monowall config page as it defaults to DHCP.  Leave the rest of the fields blank, including MAC spoofing.

To talk to the Comcast router you'll need to put static IP info into the computer/laptop you're plugging in to it.  By default, Comcast routers will not have DHCP running but should be listening on 10.1.10.1  Change your computer from using DHCP to using a fixed IPv4 of 10.1.10.2 and then plug into the Comcast box.  You should then be able to open 10.1.10.1 in a web browser and get the modem's login page.

*I haven't used monowall in ages, and could very well be wrong on this

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was exactly these things you mentioned that needed to be configured in order to work.